# checkbox click ignored if parent has onclick bind

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

Click on a checkbox is ignored if the parents "onclick" event is binded to a function. **I don't want this to happen: how can I do it?** I've stripped down my code to illustrate the problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="click: someFunction">
   Click me: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function vm() {
    this.selected = ko.observable(true);
    this.someFunction = function(){};
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jWn7R/2/). Try to click on the checkbox: it seems like nothing happens (not true: I'll explain later what happens).

Removing the call to `someFunction` to the container div result in the expected behaviour. See example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7Ln/1/). Obviously, this is not solving the problem as I need `someFunction` to be called as well.

---

I've followed the code with a debugger and noticed how the click is not actually ignored but a long chain of events happens the last one of which is reverting the value of the checkbox (thus, invalidating the click).

To follow this chain using the debugger, I've binded a click event on the checkbox.

```
<div class="container">
    Click me: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: startDebug, checked: selected" />
</div>
```

Feel free to open your dev tools and see how the expected behaviour is achieved while we're inside of the startDebug function (but reverted to the wrong one later on). Fiddle with debugger call: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa4Yf/).

Comment: Just return `true` from your function: `this.someFunction = function(){ return true;};` http://jsfiddle.net/aYkpL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return `true` from your `click` handler to trigger the browser's default click action:

```
function vm() {
    this.selected = ko.observable(true);
    this.someFunction = function(){ return true; };
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYkpL/).

See also in the documentation: [Allowing the default click action](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_click_action) (probably the next note [Preventing the event from bubbling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_4_preventing_the_event_from_bubbling) will be also relevant)

Comment: I've somehow missed that piece of documentation, very useful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nemesv, That works when you write click binding as `click : someFunction`. But it doesn't work when you write click binding as `click : function(){$root.someFunction(event)}`. Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/9uoqxfz7/57/). How to achieve the same result when you declare click binding the other way?

Comment: @VinitDivekar You are not returning the result of the someFunction in the binding: the correct syntax is: `data-bind="click : function(){return $root.clicked(event)}"` . https://jsfiddle.net/6k3astpL/